# strcpy giving segmentation fault

Tags: c, string, segmentation-fault, character, strcpy

Consider the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *cexpGen();
char *chartoStr(char c);

char c_exp[] = "1";
char expressions[2] = {'+', '-'};

int main()
{
    cexpGen();
    printf("%s", c_exp);
    return 0;
}

char *cexpGen()
{
    int now = 1;
    while ((c_exp[strlen(c_exp) - 1]) > 10)
    {
        if ((c_exp[strlen(c_exp) - 1]) == '+' || (c_exp[strlen(c_exp) - 1]) == '-')
        {
            strcpy(c_exp, chartoStr(((c_exp[strlen(c_exp) - 2]) + 1)));
            continue;
        }

        if (now = 1)
        {
            strcpy(c_exp, chartoStr(expressions[0]));
            now++;
            cexpGen();
        }

        if (now = 2)
        {
            strcpy(c_exp, chartoStr(expressions[1]));
            now++;
            cexpGen();
        }

        if (now = 3)
        {
            strcpy(c_exp, chartoStr(((c_exp[strlen(c_exp) - 1]) + 1)));
        }
    }
}

char *chartoStr(char c)
{
    char s[2] = {c, '\0'};
    return s;
}
```

I wanted to concatenate a cahracter and an string, But we don't have the function to do that, So I've defined a function chartoStr. Also c_exp and expressions varaibles aren't in read only mode, But strcpy() gives me segmentation fault. I also tried other functions any way, Like strcat, Which didn't help.

In case it helps, I debug it in VS Code. It opens `strcpy-sse2-unaligned.S` and shows segmentation fault in one of it's lines.

Is launch.json or task.json files needed? I don't think they may help, So I don't  full the question with codes, But tell me if they're needed.

Comment: `if (now = 1)` is always true and assigns the value `1` to `now`. You probably meant `if(now == 1)`. If you're using gcc, be sure to compile with `-Wall` and fix every warning.

Comment: now++; will not affect the recursive code call. Make it static or global.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use strcpy into a string with 1 character. High probability that you write out-of-bounds somewhere. Use `c_exp[0] = other_character;` instead. Overall you have multiple beginner mistakes that could be easily avoided by using a decent compiler and listening to the warning messages you get when compiling.

Comment: This `char c_exp[] = "1";` defines `c_exp` to be an array of 2 `char`. This size cannot be changed during run-time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`chartoStr()` returns a local that is no longer available at function's end as well answered by [@kiran Biradar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52399540/2410359)

```
char s[2] = {c, '\0'};
return s;  // bad, UB
```

---

An alternative to calling `chartoStr()` it to create the *string* in the calling code using a [compound literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal)  (Since C99).

```
// strcpy(c_exp, chartoStr(expressions[0]));
//            v-----------------------------v---- compound literal         
strcpy(c_exp, (char []){expressions[0], '\0'});
```

A nice attribute is that there is no expensive allocation nor pointer to free.  The *compound literal* is valid until the end of the block.

---

Note that code could employ other improvements by saving the length `size_t len = strlen(c_exp)` once early in `cexpGen()` and using it to append.

```
// strcpy(c_exp, chartoStr(expressions[0]));
c_exp[len++] = expressions[0];
c_exp[len] = '\0';
```

---

**Other Problems**

Take heed to [@alk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52399433/strcpy-giving-segmentation-fault/52400138#comment91743888_52399433) about `char c_exp[] = "1";`

`while (c_exp[strlen(c_exp) - 1]) > 10` is *undefined behavior* should `strlen(c_exp)` return 0.  Perhaps `while ((len = strlen(c_exp)) > 0 && c_exp[len - 1]) > 10`?

`if (now = 1)` is always true. [@user3386109](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52399433/strcpy-giving-segmentation-fault/52400138#comment91743063_52399433)

Answer (score 1):

You are getting segfault because you are returning address of local variable.

```
char s[2] = {c, '\0'};
    return s;
```

`s` will be destroyed once control exits  `chartoStr` function.

Compiler is also warning the same

> warning: function returns address of local variable [-Wreturn-local-addr]
>
> ```
>  return s;
>  ^
> ```

You don't need  `strcpy` to copy the single character you can directly assign.

To solve your problem you can try as below.

```
char *chartoStr(char c)
{
    char *s = malloc(2);
     s[0] = c;
     s[1] =  '\0';
    return s;
}
```

Don't forget to free `s` after work done.

Comment: Since `sizeof(char)` is *always* one, you could just `malloc(2)`.

Comment: @paxdiablo Done.